# Did I lose my ship forever?

Tags: port-royale-gold-power-and-pirates

For nostalgic reasons I was playing the original Port Royale the other night when my convoy was attacked by pirates.  Needless to say I dispatched of these black hearted scoundrels and in doing so captured one of their vessels.

I then sailed to the nearest port to do some trading, where I took the captured ship (which I had rather badly damaged in my efforts to secure) out of the convoy and left it unassigned in the port (thinking I could repair it and come back for it later rather than limp with it across the ocean at risk of further attack.

Unfortunately, I went to carry out the second part of that plan and was rather irritated to  find that I can't find it!  It doesn't display as a waiting convoy anywhere (in the list or on the map icon) and I can't remember which town I left it in!  If I try to click towns from the map I can't view them as I don't have a convoy docked there so I don't really know how best to search for it (or if it was just immediately scuttled when I left it in port unattended).

It's a long shot - but does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

By shear fluke I happened to sail my convoy into the same town where I had previously left the ship and found it fit and well waiting for me.

If anyone is in the same situation, there seems to be no other way to find the ship than sailing a convoy into towns by trial and error - there is no world map symbol (as the lone ship is not a convoy) and you can not enter a town where you just have an unassigned ship (for the same reason).

Comment: I always drop a ship or two to each town if I have a spare one. You don't know when you meet a pirate and there's nothing better than gold for free :P